# Initializing nested objects java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

If I initialize an ArrayList of ArrayLists containing LatLng objects, are the ArrayLists of LatLngs set to null or empty? Reason I ask is because when I check to make sure the first ArrayList is null, I get an IndexOutofBoundsException (size = 0, index = 0). Does this mean all of the objects have been set to empty and not null when I first initialized the object? So I don't have to initialize a new LatLng object everytime nor do I have to initialize each nested ArrayList?

My initialized object:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>> badSpots = new ArrayList<>();
int badArrayNum = 0;
```

Where I get the exception:

```
if(badSpots.get(badArrayNum)!=null){
                        badSpots.get(badArrayNum).add(badArrayNum,new LatLng(newLat,newLon));
                    }
```

Comment: Initialization is only one level deep. In your example, you create a new ArrayList in which you can happily stuff ArrayLists of LatLng objects. Mind: you only created an **empty** list; nothing else.

Comment: @Jägermeister so then if my badSpots isn't empty, say there's an arraylist at index 0, but not at index 1, is the arraylist at index 1 null or empty?

Comment: Simply read the javadoc for the collections; as the answer is: it depends. If you called "add" just once; then size is 1; and only index 0 can be accessed. If you call "add" twice ... then size is 2; and at index 1 ... you got what you "added" there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get array out of bounds error is because you havent stored anything at that index, mainly because the size is 0 since you havent inserted anything into the ArrayList. Therefore, before you do the `get` call, do a check on the size of the ArrayList to prevent a IndexOutOfBoundException. So check if `badSpots.size()>0` or a `!badSports.isEmpty()` before you do `badSpots.get(0)`.

So you still have to initialize the objects you store. And no, your LatLng object will not be initialized. The generic only ensures Type LatLng object is stored in your ArrayList.

Comment: so then if my badSpots isn't empty, say there's an arraylist at index 0, but not at index 1, is the arraylist at index 1 null or empty?

Comment: if badSpots has a size 1, `badSpots.get(1)` will throw an exception as that index doesnt exist. If you are talking about the implementation of ArrayList class itself, then it is probably null, but you don't have to worry about that